# UIImagePickerController - Custom Preview Screen

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating a custom overlay for a video camera and I would like to show a custom preview screen after the stop record button has been pressed. How would I go about doing this.

Comment: Be more specific. Have you written any code or done any research thus far?

Comment: so ive already created the overlay, but is there an easy way to create a preview, like create an overlay for the default apple video preview, or any other way @hw731